# Не получается вывести значение словаря полученного из Cisco UCM

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco

C помощью python получен словарь с данными, выгруженными из Cisco UСM. При попытке вывести значение элемента `label` появляется ошибка:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обратиться к данному элементу?

`print(new_dict["line"]["label"])` - не работает.

```
{'line': [(RPhoneLine){
   _uuid = "{E795DA96-9F71-8EF2-A196-BCA6649A9515}"
   index = "1"
   label = "Test Phone"
   display = "Test Phone"
   dirn = 
      (RDirn){
         _uuid = "{BE025CD4-FD37-5D2B-592D-FAE0D2327641}"
         pattern = "6565"
         routePartitionName = 
            (routePartitionName){
               value = "Pt_Unreachable"
               _uuid = "{15580DD8-6309-8677-623F-CD4CE32B339A}"
            }
      }
   ringSetting = "Use System Default"
   consecutiveRingSetting = "Use System Default"
   ringSettingIdlePickupAlert = "Use System Default"
   ringSettingActivePickupAlert = "Use System Default"
   displayAscii = "Test Phone"
   e164Mask = ""
   dialPlanWizardId = ""
   mwlPolicy = "Use System Policy"
   maxNumCalls = "6"
   busyTrigger = "2"
   callInfoDisplay = 
      (callInfoDisplay){
         callerName = "false"
         callerNumber = "false"
         redirectedNumber = "false"
         dialedNumber = "false"
      }
   recordingProfileName = ""
   monitoringCssName = ""
   recordingFlag = "Call Recording Disabled"
   audibleMwi = "Default"
   speedDial = None
   partitionUsage = "General"
   associatedEndusers = 
      (associatedEndusers){
         enduser[] = 
            (REnduserMember){
               userId = "testuser"
            },
      }
   missedCallLogging = "true"
   recordingMediaSource = "Gateway Preferred"
 }]}
```

Comment: Приведенная вами структура данных не является валидным словарем.

Comment: Упрощенно, начало вывода выглядит вот так, тип - кортеж: 
(<HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, (reply){
   return = 
      (return){
         phone = 
            (RPhone){               
               name = "SEP501CB00D4314"               
               lines = 
                  (lines){
                     line[] = 
                        (RPhoneLine){
                         label = "Test Phone"
                  ...

Answer (score 0):

`print(new_dict[1]["return"].phones.lines.line[0].label` - работает

```
(<HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, (reply){
   return = 
      (return){
         phone = 
            (RPhone){
               lines = 
                  (lines){
                     line[] = 
                        (RPhoneLine){
                           label = "Test Phone"
                           ...
```